# Automate creation of PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I can create what I need by hardcoding it like so:

```
$result1 = array($title[0] => array(
                                    $options_exploded[0][0],
                                    $options_exploded[0][1],
                                    $options_exploded[0][2],
                                    $options_exploded[0][3],
                                    )
                );
$result2 = array($title[1] => array(
                                    $options_exploded[1][0],
                                    $options_exploded[1][1],
                                    $options_exploded[1][2],
                                    )
                );
$result = array_merge($result1, $result2);
echo json_encode($result);
```

My problem is. How can I create the same thing but in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this, but it required a totally different approach to extracting the data from the DB. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here? It looks like you want $title[0] to equal $options_exploded[0] and $title[1] to equal $options_exploded[1]. If this is what you're trying to do, I don't see why you can't just set $result = $options_exploded.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should do it if the `$title` and `$options_exploded` keys match:

```
foreach($title as $key => $val) {
    $result[$val] = $options_exploded[$key];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```